# Removing sensitive informations from the logs using regex

Tags: regex, rubular

In my Ruby app I have the following regex that helps me with removing sensitive informations from logs:

```
/(\\"|")secure[^:]+:\s*\1.*?\1/
```

It works when in logs are the following information:

```
{"secure_data": "Test"}
```

but when instead of string I have object in logs it does not work:

```
{"secure_data": {"name": "Test"}}
```

How can I update regex to work with both scenarios?

https://rubular.com/r/h9EBZot1e7NUkS

Comment: don't use RegEx to parse JSON. Use a proper parser instead.

Comment: You may use: `"secure[^:]+:\s*(?:"[^"]*"|{[^}]*})` Or check: https://rubular.com/r/pdx04bSICE4xQX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex with negated character classes and an alternation:

```
"secure[^:]+:\s*(?:"[^"]*"|{[^}]*})
```

Inside non-capturing group `(?:"[^"]*"|{[^}]*})` we are matching a quoted string or an object that starts with `{` and ends with `}`.

[Update RegEx Demo](https://rubular.com/r/pdx04bSICE4xQX)

Answer (score 1):

The following should work for what you're trying to do. I'd suggest using a json parser though.

```
{"secure[^:]*?:\s({?(?:(?:,[^"]*?)?"[^"]*?"(?::\s"[^"]*?")?)*?)*?}?}
```

With this regex the object in secure_data may also contain multiple key-value(string)-pairs. It will still match. Other objects will not.